# Open window in JavaScript with HTML inserted

Tags: javascript, html, insert

How would I open a new window in JavaScript and insert HTML data instead of just linking to  an HTML file?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use **[window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open)** to open a new window/tab(according to browser setting) in javascript.

By using **[document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.write)** you can write HTML content to the opened window.

Comment: Also call `document.close()` after `write()` in case you have embedded JS event handler as this will trigger DOMContentLoad events.

Answer (score 165):

I would not recomend you to use `document.write` as others suggest, because if you will open such window twice your HTML will be duplicated 2 times (or more).

Use innerHTML instead

```
var win = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=780,height=200,top="+(screen.height-400)+",left="+(screen.width-840));
win.document.body.innerHTML = "HTML";
```

Comment: Good idea to use innerHTML!

Comment: Will the **body**  object be present on a newly created window?

Comment: Yes, it is always present on any page, even if you don't put it, the browser will auto-add it

Comment: Please note that if you have <script> tags inside that HTML they will not be executed.

Comment: I am opening the window like this:

`var win = window.open("", "Page Help", "newwindow", "width=1100, height=700, top=100, left=100");
win.document.body.innerHTML = "help_text";`
But the window is full screen and has no title. Why is it not respecting my settings?

Comment: @LarryMartell Try using the [`<title>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp) tag inside `win.document.head.innerHTML`

Comment: @LarryMartell you're using the API wrong. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open .. it takes 3 parameters, and perhaps you don't understand the second one.  Often, '_blank' is used in this case but you can use any string and running the same code a second time will refer to the previously opened window. `var win = window.open("", "newwindow", "width=1100, height=700, top=100, left=100"); win.document.body.innerHTML = "<html><head><title>This is the title</title></head><body>help_text</body></html>";` works for me.

Comment: Using `width=780,height=200` makes it harder to adapt to different screen sizes. Something like `width=50%, height=20%` (if that was your thinking for 1920x1080 footprint) would be better. Just not sure how that is coded for the `window.open` function/method. In the same vein, `top="+(screen.height-400)+",left="+(screen.width-840)` would be problematic.

Answer (score 35):

Here's how to do it with an HTML Blob, so that you have control over the entire HTML document:

https://codepen.io/trusktr/pen/mdeQbKG?editors=0010

This is the code, but StackOverflow blocks the window from being opened (see the codepen example instead):

```js
const winHtml = `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Window with Blob</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Hello from the new window!</h1>
        </body>
    </html>`;

const winUrl = URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([winHtml], { type: "text/html" })
);

const win = window.open(
    winUrl,
    "win",
    `width=800,height=400,screenX=200,screenY=200`
);
```

Comment: Great solution, this really helped me out on a project where adding in an extra HTML file for the new window content would have been problematic. Just to add that it's worth including `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the `<head>` of your HTML to ensure it will render any non-Latin characters.

Answer (score 33):

When you create a new window using `open`, it returns a reference to the new window, you can use that reference to write to the newly opened window via its `document` object.

Here is an example:

```js
var newWin = open('url','windowName','height=300,width=300');
newWin.document.write('html to write...');
```

Answer (score 11):

You can open a new popup window by following code:

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "newWindow", "width=500,height=700");
//window.open('url','name','specs');
```

Afterwards, you can add HTML using both `myWindow.document.write();` or `myWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "HTML";`

What I will recommend is that first you create a new html file with any name.
In this example I am using

> newFile.html

And make sure to add all content in that file such as bootstrap cdn or jquery, means all the links and scripts. Then make a div with some id or use your body and give that a `id`. in this example I have given `id="mainBody"` to my newFile.html `<body>` tag

```
<body id="mainBody">
```

Then open this file using

```
<script>    
var myWindow = window.open("newFile.html", "newWindow", "width=500,height=700");
</script>
```

And add whatever you want to add in your body tag. using following code

```
<script>    
 var myWindow = window.open("newFile.html","newWindow","width=500,height=700");  

   myWindow.onload = function(){
     let content = "<button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='window.print();'>Confirm</button>";
   myWindow.document.getElementById('mainBody').innerHTML = content;
    } 

myWindow.window.close();
 </script>
```

it is as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create an "example.html" page which has your desired html and give that page's url as parameter to window.open

```
var url = '/example.html';
var myWindow = window.open(url, "", "width=800,height=600");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this one. It worked for me very perfect.

For New window:

```
new_window = window.open(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([HTML_CONTENT], { type: "text/html" })))
```

for pop-up

```
new_window = window.open(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([HTML_CONTENT], { type: "text/html" })),"width=800,height=600")
```

Replace HTML_CONTENT with your own HTML Code
Like:

```
new_window = window.open(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["<h1>Hello</h1>"], { type: "text/html" })))
```

Answer (score 0):

*if your `window.open()` & `innerHTML` works fine, **ignore this answer**.*

*following answer only focus on `cross-origin access exception`*

---

### @key-in_short,workaround:: [for `cross-origin access exception`]

when you exec code in `main.html` -- which tries to access file `window_ImageGallery.html` by using `window.open()` & `innerHTML`

for anyone who encounter **`cross-origin access exception`**

and you dont want to disable/mess_around_with Chrome security policy

-> you may use **query string** to transfer the html code data, as a workaround.

### @details::

#### @problem-given_situation,@problem-arise_problem::

- say you exec following simple `window.open` command as other answer suggested.

  ```js
  let window_Test = window.open('window_ImageGallery.html', 'Image Enlarged Window' + $(this).attr('src'), 'width=1000,height=800,top=50,left=50');

  window_Test.document.body.innerHTML = 'aaaaaa';
  ```
- you may **encounter following `cross-origin access exception`**

  ```js
  window_Test.document.body.innerHTML = 'aaaaaa'; // < Exception here

  Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
  ```

#### => @problem-solution-workaround::

- you may use **query string** to transfer the html code data, as a workaround. <- [Transfer data from one HTML file to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502071/transfer-data-from-one-html-file-to-another)
- @eg::

  - in your `main.html`

    ```js
      // #>> open ViewerJs in a new html window
      eleJq_Img.click(function() {
        // #>>> send some query string data -- a list of <img> tags, to the new html window
        // @repeat: must use Query String to pass html code data, else you get `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.` (cross origin access issue)
        let id_ThisImg = this.id;
        let ind_ThisImg = this.getAttribute('data-index-img');

        let url_file_html_window_ImageGallery = 'window_ImageGallery.html'
          + '?queryStr_html_ListOfImages=' + encodeURIComponent(html_ListOfImages) 
          + '&queryStr_id_ThisImg=' + encodeURIComponent(id_ThisImg)
          + '&queryStr_ind_ThisImg=' + encodeURIComponent(ind_ThisImg);

        // #>>> open ViewerJs in a new html window
        let window_ImageGallery = window.open(url_file_html_window_ImageGallery, undefined, 'width=1000,height=800,top=50,left=50');
      });
    ```
  - in your `window_ImageGallery.html`

    ```js
    window.onload = function () {
      // #>> get parameter from URL
      // @repeat: must use Query String to pass html code data, else you get `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.` (cross origin access issue)
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502071/transfer-data-from-one-html-file-to-another
      let data = getParamFromUrl();

      let html_ListOfImages = decodeURIComponent(data.queryStr_html_ListOfImages);
      let id_ThisImgThatOpenedTheHtmlWindow = decodeURIComponent(data.queryStr_id_ThisImg);
      let ind_ThisImgThatOpenedTheHtmlWindow = decodeURIComponent(data.queryStr_ind_ThisImg);

      // #>> add the Images to the list
      document.getElementById('windowImageGallery_ContainerOfInsertedImages').innerHTML = html_ListOfImages;

      // -------- do your stuff with the html code data 

    };

    function getParamFromUrl() {
      let url = document.location.href;
      let params = url.split('?')[1].split('&');
      let data = {};
      let tmp;
      for (let i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
        tmp = params[i].split('=');
        data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
      }
      return data
    }
    ```

#### @minor-note::

- (seems) sometimes you **may not** get the `cross-origin access exception`

  - due to, if you *modify the html of 'window_ImageGallery.html' in `main.html`* **before** `window_ImageGallery.html` is loaded

    - above statement is based on my test

      & another answer -- [window.open: is it possible open a new window with modify its DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192239/window-open-is-it-possible-open-a-new-window-with-modify-its-dom)
    - if you want to make sure to see that Exception,

      you can try to **wait** until the opening html window finish loading, then continue execute your code

      @eg::

      - use defer() <- [Waiting for child window loading to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372022/waiting-for-child-window-loading-to-complete)

        ```js
        let window_ImageGallery = window.open('window_ImageGallery.html', undefined, 'width=1000,height=800,top=50,left=50');

        window_ImageGallery.addEventListener("unload", function () {
          defer(function (){
            console.log(window_ImageGallery.document.body); // < Exception here
          });
        });

        function defer (callback) {
            var channel = new MessageChannel();
            channel.port1.onmessage = function (e) {
                callback();
            };
            channel.port2.postMessage(null);
        }
        ```
      - or use `sleep()` with `async` [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

        ```js
        eleJq_Img.click(async function() {
          ...
          let window_Test = window.open( ...
          ...
          await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
          console.log(window_Test.document.body.innerHTML); // < Exception here
        });
        ```
  - or you get **`null`** pointer exception

    if you try to access elements in `window_ImageGallery.html`

---

<sub>- @minor-comment::

  There are too many similar Posts about the `cross-origin` issue. And there are some posts about `window.open()`

  Idk which post is the best place to place the answer. And I picked here.</sub>