# Open New Tab with Results from JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

This doesn't work:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' target='_blank' onclick='do_stuff()' >Open</a>
```

And neither does this

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' target='_blank'onclick='window.open(do_stuff(), "_blank");' >View</a>
```

It might be clear what I am trying to do.  I need to open up a new tab with the results of a JavaScript function.  Is there another way I can try to do this?

Comment: What results are you trying to pass to new `window`?

Comment: @guest271314 just HTML.

Comment: Can you show your code for `do_stuff()`?

Comment: `do_stuff()` calls ajax and returns HTML.  Not much more than that.  the return function populates something like `$("#myDiv").html(data);`

Comment: Have you checked [this answer for HTML content using window.open](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19078591/2196341). Might help

Comment: @TheUknown  That would be good for small HTML content, but I am basically opening up a page to large website,

Comment: Got ya. Well, it can still work but probably not the best way around. You can escape html using ``` back quote.

Comment: @KickingLettuce _"do_stuff() calls ajax and returns HTML"_ `do_stuff()` returns results asynchronously?

Comment: Nope, nope.  My fault, I apologize.  I looked at the code closer and realized `do_stuff()` does not print out HTML.  It does an `document.location.href` at the end.  This is easy to do what I need now, bby using a `_blank` in `window.open`'s 2nd param.  However, I'll keep this question around because it is still something I would like to do in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open new window (tab) and save it to a variable, then change it's content to your function output:

```
<button onclick="clicked()">Test</button>

<script>

var clicked = function () {
  var new_page = window.open();
  new_page.document.write("output");
}

</script>
```

You can use JS to create divs and change it's content:

```
new_page.document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "test";
```

Comment: I really like that jQuery option.  Let me try and get back.

Comment: sorry, changed my code to JS and it should work now, will try to come up with a version for jQuery

Comment: Thanks, this code works so I will mark as correct.  However, as I explained above just now, I ended up not needing to dot his with my project as I misread my code a bit.  Thanks for your help!  I may use this in the future.