# access HTML element in new tab via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, focus, element, document

I'd like to access an element in a new tab and write a value to it.

I created a site (html) with different buttons, which start a javascript, which will open the new tab and should look for specified element by id in the new tab.

When it's found, it should enter e.g. a username.

But it never finds the element in the the new tab. I guess the focus still is on the first document.

How can I change the focus of the javascript to the new tab?

Edit:

Sorry, here is the code of the page with the buttons:

```
<button type="button" onclick="opencem()">CEM</button>

<button type="button" onclick="vascologin()">VASCO</button>

<script src="login.js">
</script>
```

And this is the js code with your suggestions:

```
function opencem() {
var newTab = window.open('https://slkub...');
newTab.focus();
newTab.document.getElementById('f-username').value = 'test';
}
```

But still i get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
at opencem (login.js:235)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (login.html:29)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the window and save it to a variable, and then change the content based on that variable.

```
var newTab = window.open();
newTab.document.getElementById("id").value = username;
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40031206/14006497.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provide some code to see how you are opening the tab.

If you do it with `window.open`, you can focus like this:

```
var newTab = window.open("https://example.com", "_blank");
newTab.focus();
```