# How to create HTML page by code

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to open a new target by code.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", 
    "window.open('" + gridHTML + "','_blank')", true);
```

But I get an empty tab. How can I send some html code (which I generate) so that the tab is not empty?

Comment: `window.open` just takes a URL, maybe you want `document.write`?

Comment: @Equalsk may be, if I do document.write, can I open this page?

Comment: See the answers here, I'm sure one will work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109205/open-window-in-javascript-with-html-inserted