# Change a modal dialog to open in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is the following code that will open up a modal page within the parent page, but I want it to be opened in a new small window. What would be the easiest way to achieve this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal

This is an example form W3Schools, I actually have to change another modal view in a web project, but I don't know what to look for, so I asked my question based on this sample hoping to be able to replicate the solution on the other project as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19078591/586051

Comment: W3 Schools has another article for opening new browser windows: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp also here's a SO answer already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript however, opening new browser windows means you are going into a fight with pop-up blockers and users themselves. Everything else being the same, internal modal dialogs are much easier for you and much more pleasant for the user when done right.

Comment: I think the OP wants the modal itself to be in a separate window which, basically, can't be done.