# chrome browser does not show png image on print preview page nor on saved pdf file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am trying to add some png image to my print page with jquery, but am not able to do that, any help would be appreciated.
Chrome version:Version 70.0.3538.102.
My code:
Here am appending all my image to "myImages" div and then printing.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    w=window.open();
    w.document.write($('#myImages').html());
    w.print();
    w.close();
}, 100);
```

Comment: You have "myImage" in the description and '#myImages' as id. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, thats right.

Comment: @dcalap:sorry, typo mistake my bad, its "myImages".

Comment: [Open window in JavaScript with HTML inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109205/open-window-in-javascript-with-html-inserted)

Comment: Maybe this will work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/rd8f6pLf/

Comment: @dcalap:still getting blank image, though this time am getting atlest image tag div borders
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFsEx.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it work for me when i change this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   w=window.open();
   w.document.write($('#myImages').html());
   w.print();
   w.close();
}, 100);
```

to this:

```
w=window.open();
w.document.write($('#myImages').html());
setTimeout(function () {
   w.print();
   w.close();
}, 100);
```