# Creating html game play on javascript pop up window

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an html game on the pop up window. When the user clicks on the button, they should be able to view the game on a pop up javascript window, another informal name for this could be game in a game.
My code is as follows:

HTML -

```
<input type="image" id="buttonimage1" alt="game1"
    src="canon.png" onclick="openWindow();">
```

JavaScript

```
function openWindow()
 {
    newWindow = window.open("", null, "height=300,width=500,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");   
}
```

I would like to implement the html js game code for tictactoe (XandO) given on this website https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/NAOYuT  on my pop up window. Do I include it as a new div and add it to my html code for openWindow? Or are there any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured the answer through innerHTML as in:

```
newWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "HTML";
```

Another way is by:

```
newWindow.document.write();
```

This is the link to the post on stackoverflow which explains document.write in detail : [Open window in JavaScript with HTML inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109205/open-window-in-javascript-with-html-inserted)