# Posting data and loading a new page using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code that is run when I press a button:

```
function document_preview_changes()
{
    var url = 'lib/chart-preview-embed.php';
    var data =
    {
        gamesrecord_id: gamesrecord_id,
        style_id: style_id,
        layout_id: layout_id,
        format_id: format_id,
        game_id: game_id,
        game_seo: game_seo,
        ten_bool: ten_bool,
        svg_bool: svg_bool,
        commandouter_table: commandouter_table
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}

function reqListener ()
{
    console.log(this.responseText);
}
```

I want to post the data to 'chart-preview-embed.php' and load the PHP file in a new window. However, nothing happens. (No errors either.) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you forgot to add an event listener to the xhr to listen for the load event  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Okay, I added an event listener. I want to load the document in a new window however.

Comment: yeah just add the code to open it in a new window inside of the function

Comment: Could you help with this? It is the part I don't understand.

Comment: I'm guessing you are getting back some html from your ajax request? You should do `console.log(this);` to see what all you are getting back. Once you have found whatever it is you want to display in a new window, this should help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19078591/2079345

Comment: Is there no other way? I need users to be able to save the page (and CSS, images, etc.) to disk but you can't do that when generating the page using JavaScript.