Chrome - In the new tab "Save As..." disabled in right click menu when displaying generated HTML
In my frontend app I generate the HTML page as string and then open a new tab with JavaScript and write the html to the tab's document, like so:
const newTab = window.open('about:blank', '', '');
newTab.document.write(this.fullRenderedHTML);

As a result the Save as option in the right click menu is disabled. Is there a way to make it possible for the user to save the page?
I expect the user to be able to save the generated HTML.
Here's a codepen link to reproduce the issue.
https://codepen.io/socreative/pen/bGJxRLK
Click the Open Tab button then try saving the page in the new tab

Can't reproduce (on Firefox 124.0.2 [64-bit]). Please add enough code to create a [mre]

This is probably because Save As saves the original sources and about:blank is empty. You can try the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109205/open-window-in-javascript-with-html-inserted

@Randy That would suggest the "Save as"-option is actually not disabled though, whilst OP stated "As a result the Save as option in the right click menu is disabled"

@DarkBee Updated the question with a codepen link

Works as is for me. Which browser are you using?

@DarkBee Chrome
