# Javascript function call across HTML windows

Tags: javascript, function, scope, window

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87359/can-i-pass-a-javascript-variable-to-another-browser-window) page I should be able to call parameters and functions of child windows, but it is not working for me.

```
var w = window.open("index.html");
console.log(w);
console.log(w.foo);
```

`console.log(w)` shows that there is a function named `foo` but `console.log(w.foo)` outputs `undefined`. Is this a security issue?

---

**EDIT** Here is some more functionality:

child.html (omitting the body):

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  test = 123 ;
  function foo(arg){
   //do something
  }
 </script>
</head>
```

parent.html:

```
var w = window.open("child.html");
console.log(w);
//outputs all the methods and parameters
console.log(w.foo);
//outputs 'undefined'
console.log(w.test);
//outputs 'undefined'
```

---

**EDIT 2** Also I should explain why I need to pass arguments as someone will inevitably ask me why I can't 'just hard code it'. I have an HTML canvas element, and every time the user right clicks, there is a right click menu with the option 'list shapes underneath'.

When the user clicks this menu item, I want to pass a list of all the shapes underneath that click and to display it in a new window. Here are the problems I am facing:

1. I can't pass it as an argument b/c I don't know whether the window has been loaded (I can't seem to change the `onload` function either)
2. I can't have the child window query the parent window b/c the right click menu disappears after clicking it.

Comment: Do you mean a jsfiddle example or just a self contained script?

Comment: I have no idea how I would implement an example on jsfiddle

Comment: I believe they have a usage FAQ. Either way, we can't help without knowing what your code looks like.

Comment: I updated it with some more information

Comment: There shouldn't be a security issue if the parent and child window both contain pages from the same domain. Has the child page (index.html) finished loading at the point that you try to access its function(s)? I generally find it easiest to either have the child page request values it needs from the parent, like `x = window.opener.parentFunction();`, or tell the parent that it is ready (at the end of child's onload:) `window.opener.childLoaded();` and have the parent wait for that function call before it tries to manipulate the child.

Comment: Just saw your update. What happens if you actually call `w.foo()` rather than logging the function itself as `w.foo`?

Comment: nnnn, if I call w.foo() I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'foo'`

Comment: wrt to the child page not having finished loading, I tried a 10 second delay before the console.log statement but the problem persisted, I'll try the child request method as well

Comment: does the child window have the same domain name?

Comment: I'm testing this on my home system. I am logging in via my local ip address, and both files are in the same folder, if that helps.

Comment: Your approach to use a delay is good and should work(it takes some time to load a window). Please provide more information about how/where you call `window.open()` and `setTimeout()` , it may be a scope-issue in `setTimeout()`

Comment: I tried using the delay method. I set the child window's onload function to `onload = "loaded=true"` and then I called setTimeout with a 1000 ms frequency and a function which checks `w.loaded==true`. If it has loaded, I try setting a property, and/or calling a property and still I get nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not giving the DOM of the child window a chance to load before trying to inspect its contents.

`console.log(w)` appeared to work by displaying `Window` or similar immediately, but in fact it's just that by the time your human fingers got around to expanding the item details in the console, the properties and methods *were* present.

When I inject a delay with help from a Firebug breakpoint, I can see the child window's properties like this just fine.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372022/waiting-for-child-window-loading-to-complete) talks about adding onLoad event listeners for children. Using its accepted answer, how about:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// parent.html
var w;

function lol() {
    console.log(w.foo);
    console.log(w.test);
}

w = window.open("child.html");
console.log(w);
w.addEventListener('load', lol, true);
</script>
```

(I was also able to achieve success with a 1s `setTimeout` delay.)

Comment: I'll give it a shot, although I doubt it will work since a 10s timeout delay didn't work for me... WOW it actually worked

Comment: @puk: Whatever you did to implement the 10s timeout was wrong. Again, you haven't shown us, so we can't tell you what that was.

Comment: Well it worked somewhat. It works for `foo` and `test` because they are hard coded. But if, for example,  I do `function lol(){ w.xyz = 123; console.log(w.xyz)}` the output is still `undefined`.

Comment: @puk: I'm not sure whether you're allowed to inject new properties into a child window.

Comment: Is there any way to 'ask' the child to inject new properties into itself? ie. `w.addEventListener('load', lol, true, args)`? I have to step out, will check again in a few hours.

Comment: @puk: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Tomalak: I have a value that constantly changes and it's difficult to keep a global copy of it (see EDIT2 of my question). I need some way to pass the correct copy to the child window.

Comment: OK turns out one IS allowed to inject properties into a new window. The problem is what I was injecting was itself undefined. I have a helper function which retrieves shapes like so `$$('shapeName')` and I was trying to access property `test` of it and pass it to the child window like so `$$('shapName').test` but instead I had `'shapeName'.test` and for some reason their was no syntax error.

Comment: @puk: Strings are objects with properties. :) Consider, for example, `var bool = "myString".match(/someRegex/);`

Comment: I see. I'm not a big fan of some of javascript's choices. I'm a Python man myself. I think a line should be drawn differentiating objects from literals. But I won't get into that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @puk: Strictly speaking there is a line, but implicit conversions blur it in practice.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is rather simple if you look at your code logically

The following two calls will only work inside the window you open.

```
console.log(w.foo);
//outputs 'undefined'
console.log(w.test);
//outputs 'undefined'
```

i.e.

```
console.log(foo);
```

in the parent window javascript, and

```
console.log(window.parent.foo);
```

in the child window javascript.

Comment: I am not familiar with `window.parent`. Do you mean `window.opener`?

Comment: I'm really sorry eaglstorem but I am not following your logic. `foo` is defined in the child window, why would the parent call `console.log(foo)` and the child call `console.log(window.opener.foo)`

Comment: @eaglestorm: He wants to access the properties of the child window from the parent window. And I think you have it backward as to where `foo` is declared.

Comment: My bad I did get it backwards