# Angularjs - make synchroneous call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am downloading a text file from server.
I want to execute the next command once the file has been downloaded.

I am doing this :

```
 window.open(location.pathname+'api/generateFile','_blank');
 $scope.searchBls();
```

Is there a way to make sure that **$scope.searchBls()** is called only once **window.open** has finished?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Waiting for child window loading to complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372022/waiting-for-child-window-loading-to-complete)

Comment: Subtle difference: _"I want to execute the next command once the file has been downloaded."_

Answer (score 1):

Bind to the `window.onload` event

```
var win = window.open(location.pathname+'api/generateFile','_blank');
win.onload = function() {
    $scope.searchBls();
};
```

Comment: win = window.open opens a new tab and asks me to save the file but $scope.searchBls() is not called.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple: [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

```
var win = window.open(location.pathname+'api/generateFile','_blank');
win.onload = $scope.searchBls;
```

You might want to handle the case where the popup has been blocked. In that case win will be undefined