# How to close when a tab when download finish?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a bot to download a files from a website. The url is `example.com/1/download example.com/2/download example.com/3/download`

And I create a javascript code like:

```
i = 0;
while(i <= 100){
    window.open("https://example.com/" + i + "/download", "_blank");
    i++;
}
```

This works, but I like to close the page after download the file.

Any idea?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1372096/4949005 does that solve your problem?

Comment: is the window on your origin?

Comment: also creating that many popups will surely get blocked

Comment: Could you define exactly what sort of "bot" you mean? Is this a browser extension/injected JS/part of a page you own?

Comment: This won't work. According to browser spec, only pop ups that are opened as a result of user action will be allowed. Others will be blocked.

Comment: it's not a my page. My script is download the files from other website

Answer (score 0):

`window.close()` will close the current window.`

You can execute a script that will call `window.close()` after the file is successfully downloaded.

Comment: it's not my website. My script is download the files from other website

Comment: Can you include my edited answer logic in your script? That should work fine.

Comment: There is no way to detect if the file has been downloaded unfortunatly.